# DataTables not sorting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables for my project but its sorting function does not work properly. I have tried every single solutions in here but none of them worked for me as well as it does not show the error in the console. I think in my code there is a jQuery conflict. How can I solve this issue? any help?

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-bordered table-hover contact-list" cellspacing="0"
                       width="100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {#                            <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox"></th>#}
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {% for contact in contacts %}
                        <tbody>
                        <tr data-id="{{ contact.id }}" class="clickable-row"
                            data-href="{% url 'contact-detail' contact.id %}"
                            style="cursor: pointer; ">
                            {#                                <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" id="check"></th>#}
                            <td>{{ contact.client_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ contact.client_company_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ contact.work_phone }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
                {% csrf_token %}

$('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
```

as you can see it is a material bootstrap design datatables. In the example shown it works but when i add to my project it does not.

Comment: Your code is summarized in 2 lines? The 2 lines provided is working fine, no error. Maybe if you post a live example we can help you to solved your issu.

Comment: here above you can look

Comment: what do you mean by "not work properly"? is it sorts but wrong way, or not working at all?

Comment: The selector `.dataTables_length` does not exist on your html code.

Comment: when i click column it does not sort at all. Only its icons are working but not sorting

Comment: Note: the tag `tbody` is into your loop, you can export it outside the for loop.

Comment: oops the error was tbody why I did not notice about that:)) @R3tep thank you very much for advice

Comment: @HienNguyen Please stop making edits that apply code formatting to the names of products and libraries. It is not warranted or wanted. This is the second time I've found edits of this kind made by you.

Comment: @HereticMoney, did you see the jqeury is typo need correct in my edited?

Comment: @HienNguyen I did not, so I edited that, and *only that*. Wasn't terribly difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html table is "not valid" (*It is valid if you want to create multiple table into an parent table*). This can make some issue with Datatable. I think sorting is done, but you do not see it, because it sort by tbody tag and there is one line sorted by tbody. The tbody tags are not sorted only the tr inside

Try to remove the `tbody` into your loop and export it outside the for loop.

```
<tbody>
  {% for contact in contacts %}
  // ...
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

---

**Note**: `cellspacing="0"` is an old version of html. You can replace it by the css property `border-spacing`